# Adding numbers on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick, increment

Trying to increment numbers with a click, you can see by clicking my jsfiddle the issue that I am having, first two clicks register 0 and then the numbers increase 10 at a time afterwards

http://jsfiddle.net/jamcrowe/LvwDb/1/

```
var online = 0;
var creative = 0;
var technical = 0;
var analyst = 0;
var managerial = 0;

function  me() {
    $('#one').click(function(){
        creative +=5;
        online ++;
        managerial ++;
    });
    $('#two').click(function(){
        creative +=5;
        online ++;
        managerial ++;
    });
    $('#three').click(function(){
        creative +=5;
        online ++;
        managerial ++;
    });
    alert(creative, online, managerial);
}
```

Comment: You're assigning the click handlers multiple times. You don't need `me` function at all http://jsfiddle.net/LvwDb/2/

Comment: What do u suggest for a resolve? first time trying to develop with increments. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: have you checked the link I provided? "first time trying to develop with increments" --- it has **nothing** to do with them actually, but about how you deal with event handlers.

Comment: Yes resolved the issue, Cheers dude!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the events in jQuery AND in the DOM. I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for but I'm guessing it's something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wnfBn/

```
var online = 0;
var creative = 0;
var technical = 0;
var analyst = 0;
var managerial = 0;

$('#one,#two,#three').click(me);
function me() {
    creative += 5;
    online++;
    managerial++;
    alert(creative + ':' + online + ':' + managerial);
};
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for, If I was looking to pass these values into an array which way would I go about it

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "pass these values into an array"

Comment: Assume I had ten divs and each time a div is clicked the incremented number would go into an array, allowing to print the value of eg div three, by getting it through the array[2] , sorry if that doesnt make sense

Comment: "You are binding the events in jQuery AND in the DOM" --- in javascript and html. All the event handlers are bound in DOM.

Comment: If you look at the fiddle link @zerkms I removed the click events from the dom

Comment: @SamCrowe If you want an associative array I'd use a JavaScript object. So you could create a single object to use rather than variables: `var all = {'online': 0, 'creative':0, 'technical':0, 'analyst':0, 'managerial':0}`. Then you can increment each section of the object in your onClick function. For example: `all.creative += 5;`. This way all of your variables would be wrapped up into a single JavaScript object. In this brief example that object is named `all`.

Comment: @Luke Cordingley: it's not DOM, it's html. You have removed the event handlers from HTML. DOM and HTML terms aren't interchangeable. There are still event handlers in the DOM, they are assigned by jquery